# Simple Navigation Controller not being created

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

Created a simple navigation controller based application.  Application delegate class has Outlets for window and navcontroller.

MainWindow.xib has a Window and a navigation controller.  Files owner is UIApplication and I have an Application Delegate (class is of course my App Delegate) with an outlet to the window and the nav controller, plus a delegate connected to the Files Owner.

In applicationDidFinishLaunching I am trying to set the window's rootViewController to the navigationController but the Outlet for the navigationController is nil and (of course) the application comes up with a blank window...and the error "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the Navigation controller itself have a root view controller?  A navigation controller cannot exist solely on its own.  It is a wrapper view around other ViewControllers.  There should be a setting in the view controller properties tab in Interface Builder that will let you set either another view controller in the xib as its root, or load it from a different xib.

Comment: Sure View Controller property has another NIB name and it shows in the IB as the "first" view. Curiously it seems the IBOutlet for the window is no set either.  Seems to imply the application had yet to load the NIB even though I see it referenced in the plist.

Comment: Nuts, I am an idiot, somehow the plist value for the main nib got blown out.  Sorry for the fire drill.